# Error al generar vista o controlador

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Estoy intentando generar una nueva vista con ASP.NET MVC C#, pero cuando creo la vista me salen este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he intentado limpiar, recompilar la solución, cerrar visual studio, entre otras cosas y aún no se logra solucionar.

El mismo problema pasa cuando intento crear un controlador

- No estoy empleando Entity Framework

Comment: Hola, por favor indica en la pregunta el código del Controlador y del Modelo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abre tu consola de comandos y escribe regedit, luego dirigete a esta ruta:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Client

Luego le das donde dice DisabledByDefault y en value data pones un 1.

Espero te funcione.